# Right half zero in boost converters

Tags: voltage, power

When we increase the duty cycle in boost converters, why does the output voltage first decrease and then increase. After the time associated with the right half zero has elapsed then output voltage increases. What is physical meaning of a right half pole zero? Why does this output voltage first decrease then increase? I want a detailed answer.

Comment: Well if you want an answer "in very detail" you should make all effort that your question is as detailed as necessary. Include schematic, background, etc, and write the question correctly (spaces, capitals, etc : that makes it easier to read, that's basic politeness).

Comment: Edited and -1'ed for laziness.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are referring to the effect of a right-half s-plane zero on the transient response of a transfer function. If such a zero is on the real axis it acts as a differentiator and subtracts from the 'natural response' (i.e. the response without the zero). Depending on the numerator TF coefficients, this zero may cause an initial negative-going response.

By way of illustration consider the unit step response of the following unity DC gain, 2nd order s-TF:

\$G(s)=\dfrac{2}{s^2+3s+2}\$

Which factorises to: \$G(s)=\dfrac{2}{(s+1)(s+2)}\$

Applying a unit step as input, gives the output: \$Y(s)=\dfrac{2}{s(s+1)(s+2)}\$

Partial fractions decomposes this to: \$Y(s)= \dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac{2}{s+1}+\dfrac{1}{s+2}\$

and the associated time response is: \$y(t)=1 - 2e^{-t} +e^{-2t}\$

The first 4sec of this response is shown by the red line in the Excel chart, below.

If now we add a zero to this TF, located at, say, \$s=1\$, the s-TF becomes:

\$G^*(s)=\dfrac{2(1-s)}{(s+1)(s+2)}\$ and the unit step response is:

\$Y^*(s)=\dfrac{2(1-s)}{s(s+1)(s+2)}\$

Now, we can write this function as: \$Y^*(s)=Y(s)-sY(s)\$, which means we can use a neat trick for working out the time domain unit step response, since multiplying a Laplace function by \$s\$ is equivalent to differentiating that function in the time domain. Thus we can say that:

\$y^*(t) = y(t) -\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt} = (1 - 2e^{-t} +e^{-2t}) - (2e^{-t}-2e^{-2t})\$, and this gives:

\$y^*(t)=1 - 4e^{-t} +3e^{-2t}\$

This is the blue plot in the Excel chart, below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxZaif.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Physically, here's what going on. In a boost converter, energy is transferred from \$V_{in}\$ to the inductor when the switch is on and the diode is off. During this time, *no* energy is transferred from the inductor to the output capacitor.

Now, when you increase the duty cycle, the switch spends more time being on and the diode spends more time being off. Eventually, the inductor current will rise enough to deliver more average current to the load, which increases the voltage. But that takes time. Right after you increase the duty cycle, the inductor current is still about the same but it's connected to the load for a smaller fraction of the cycle. This means the *average* current delivered to the load goes down. That's your RHP zero.

An extreme example might help. Imagine a boost converter with a huge inductor that goes from 50% duty cycle to 99.9% duty cycle. For the first several cycles, the inductor current barely changes at all, but the average current delivered to the load drops by a factor of 500!